# energy conservation in an electric circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation

Define a reactive (lossless) and reciprocal two-port by its impedance matrix $[Z]$, so that $[Z]+[\bar Z] = [0]$  and let the source impedance and open circuit source voltage be $Z_s$ and $V_s$ at port $1$. We terminate the output with load impedance $Z_L$ at port $2$. It is easy to see that the input impedance is $Z_{in} = Z_{11}- \frac{Z_{12}^2}{Z_{22}+Z_L}$. Now if we select the parameters of $[Z]$ and the load impedance $Z_L$ so that $\bar Z_s = Z_{in}$ (conjugate impedance match) then there will be maximum dissipation in the load impedance because we have assumed that the two-port is lossless.

It is also quite easy to show that with conjugate input match one will also have automatically satisfied $\bar Z_{out} =Z_{L}$ where $Z_{out} = Z_{22}-\frac{Z_{12}^2} {Z_{11} +Z_s}$. In other words the conjugate input match *forces* the conjugate output match to hold. This is a bit surprising to me and it must be a form energy conservation. But how?

Comment: Isn't this just a form of reciprocity? You can turn your circuit around and the output becomes the input. If you have no reflection one way, you can have no reflection the other way.

Comment: I don't think so, because conjugate match assumes *fixed* source voltage $V_s$, and this is how you get the input port matched but when you look at it from port $2$ the voltage depends on the 2-port network and then I lose my intuition and rely only on manipulating the matrix elements.